# Possibilities of tracing REST trace time with azure log analytics similar to zipkin

Tags: azure, zipkin, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

We are in process to keep all monitoring and logging stuff outside of AKS. we got some success with Azure log analytics as well. I am checking if Azure log analytics provide any feature similar to zipkin. i.e. providing trace of REST API.

Comment: I dont think it does, but Application Insights [does that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-tracing)

Answer (score 2):

Application Insights users would also be able to leverage the distributed tracing offered through Zipkin by instrumenting their services using existing libraries. To use the Application Insights back-end store, configure your Zipkin server instance to use the Application Insights [plug-in](https://github.com/openzipkin-attic/zipkin-azure/pulls). This integration makes monitoring and debugging your overall end-to-end applications much easier.

Once you have the data in Application Insights, you can always perform [cross-resource log queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query) between Application Insights and Log Analytics.

Additional Documentation Reference -

[Zipkin to Application Insights Module](https://github.com/openzipkin-attic/zipkin-azure/issues/33)

[Zipkin-Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftrservertigerteam/2017/05/10/introducing-zipkin-azure/)

[Send Log Data to Azure Monitor with HTTP Data Collector API (public preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api)

Hope the above information helps.